# Parsing a key, value from file into dictionary using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked around this site for examples like mine, but could find no answers.

The file I'm parsing is a simple file with key value pairs separated by a colon.

```
one:two
three:four
five:six
seven:eight
nine:ten
sample:demo
```

I thought there should be a simple solution using dictionary comprehension.

My first attempt was

`fin = open('f00.txt', 'r')`

`L = {kv[0]:kv[1] for line in fin for kv in line.strip().split(':')}`

this produced

`{'o': 'n', 't': 'e', 'f': 'i', 's': 'a', 'e': 'i', 'n': 'i', 'd': 'e'}`

The one way I was able to get results was this

`L = {line.strip().split(':')[0]:line.strip().split(':')[1] for line in fin}`

But that required calling `split` twice (indexed by 0 and 1)

Another way I was able to get results was:

```
d = {}
for line in fin:
    kv = line.strip().split(':')
    d[kv[0]] = kv[1]
```

`{'one': 'two', 'three': 'four', 'five': 'six', 'seven': 'eight', 'nine': 'ten', 'sample': 'demo'}`

Just wondering if there is a simple comprehension for what is a trivial task.

Thanks for any imput you might provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict` with a comprehension:

```
result = dict(i.strip('\n').split(':') for i in open('filename.txt'))
```

Output:

```
{'one': 'two', 'three': 'four', 'five': 'six', 'seven': 'eight', 'nine': 'ten', 'sample': 'demo'}
```

Comment: Just as I was typing the same answer! Although `strip` doesn't need an argument and I added `maxsplit=1` to `split`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('f00.txt', 'r') as fh:
    d = dict(line.strip().split(':') for line in fh)
```